# How do I use token auth for Github Packages from Gradle?

Tags: maven, github, gradle, authorization, token

The example configuration on https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages doesn't seem to work, as it looks like GitHub packages doesn't actually accept Basic auth. I have the token from GitHub retrieved from https://github.com/settings/tokens but I don't see a way to use it for Bearer auth in Gradle.

I am asking this in order to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

In the repository section of your `gradle.build.kts`, include the following:

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven("https://maven.pkg.github.com/<OWNER>/<GIT_REPO>") {
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
            name = "Authorization"
            value = "Bearer ${project.findProperty("gpr.token") as String}"
        }
        authentication {
            create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing `<OWNER>` with the name of the user or organization that owns the repo and and `<GIT_REPO>` with the name of the git repository that generates the package. You then add the token you generated on https://github.com/settings/tokens to `gradle.properties` in the same directory as your `build.gradle.kts`. It should look like:

```
gpr.token=<Token, without quotes>
```

The file may already exist with other settings, you don't need to remove them. **DO NOT COMMIT THIS FILE**.

If this still does not work, verify that the token you generated has the `read:packages` permission. If it doesn't, you'll need to generate a new token.

Hopefully this saves you the 4 hours it took me to figure out what was happening.

Comment: You SHOULD NOT place credentials in the project's `gradle.properties` file. This file contains important variables for building projects and should be commited. Without it your project becomes quadriplegic. You want to store those variables in the user's global `gradle.properties` file instead which is usually located in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties` that usually defaults to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`